# Splitting a String with Delimiters into Dummy Variables

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

So the goal is to take a table like this:

| Person | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| Matt | A;B;C; |
| Sandy | B;D; |
| Charles | A;C;D; |

And transform it to this:

| Person | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Matt | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Sandy | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Charles | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I feel there is likely an appropriate way to handle this in `tidyverse` but none of the `pivot`, `unnest`, or `mutate` methods seem ideal in a way that doesn't involve a lot of messy processing.

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: `v <- unique(unlist(strsplit(data$Answer, ';'))); data[v] <- lapply(v, function(x) +grepl(x, data$Answer))`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100887/split-a-column-of-concatenated-comma-delimited-data-and-recode-output-as-factors or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use `tidyr::separate_rows()` to move your data to a longer format.

Once all your answers are extracted, it is easy to pivot it back to a wide format with `tidyr::pivot_wider()`

```r
library(tidyverse)
d <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Person,  ~Answer,
  "Matt", "A;B;C;",
  "Sandy",   "B;D;",
  "Charles", "A;C;D;"
)

d |> 
  tidyr::separate_rows(Answer, sep = ";") |> 
  filter(Answer != "") |> 
  mutate(value = 1) |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Answer,
    values_from = value,
    values_fill = 0
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Person      A     B     C     D
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Matt        1     1     1     0
#> 2 Sandy       0     1     0     1
#> 3 Charles     1     0     1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know about `separate_rows` and it works perfectly

Now to figure out how to map it across multiple columns using purrr :P

Comment: Depending on how your data looks like, purrr may not be the easiest way to do. 

feel free to share another example!